# Is there a python tool that generates a coverage-like report but for exceptions a function will raise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, profiling

I'm looking for a tool that reports all the types of exceptions that could be raised from functions. i.e ones that is trying to explicitly handle.

If I had this example code, in a script or some function etc. I could run this tool and it would report `OSError, ValueError, Exception` as the output.

```
try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except OSError as err:
    print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
except ValueError:
    print("Could not convert data to an integer.")
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
```

Comment: Does it report which exceptions are raised, or which exception are handled?

Comment: It should list the ones that are listed in the function / script. So ones its expecting to handle. Will update post